# Why does vim behave differently inside a function?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to get the following to work inside a function.

```
let pat = 'set'
:execute "normal /" . pat . "\<CR>"
```

However, when I run it like this (literally copy paste into vim)

```
:function! BSearch(pat)
   execute "normal /" . a:pat . "\<CR>"
endfunction
:call BSearch('tag')
```

It does a search for tag, but doesn't do any of the highlighting. "set" is still highlighted, and if I press `n` it goes to "set", not "tag".

I am at my wits end -- it seems that inside the function execute just behaves differently.

Please help if you know a workaround.

## Great workaround in answer

I was able to write out my full command and have it work as I expected

`command! -nargs=1 Ack2 execute "Ack " . <q-args> | execute "/".<q-args>`

The `ack.vim` extension didn't highlight the terms I searched for. Since I have configured my search to use perl regular expressions (and `ag` uses perl regular expressions, which is what I use as my searcher), the terms are now not only highlighted, I can step through them using `n` like I would any normal search (except it is now across my whole project obviously).

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at this:

```
:h function-search-undo
```

Here is the whole paragraph:

```
The last used search pattern and the redo command "."
will not be changed by the function.  This also
implies that the effect of |:nohlsearch| is undone
when the function returns.
```

Maybe you can move your search into a user command, for example:

```
command! -nargs=1 BSearch execute "/".<q-args>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! I'll post the full glorious command I am now using.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need `normal` to `execute` a `/` search. For your case, this should suffice:

```
function! BSearch(pat)
  execute "/" . a:pat
endfunction
```

Comment: huh, that is interesting. Unfortunately it still behaves differently in command mode and in the function :(  (it behaves the same as it did before)

Comment: Updated example to include full function, which works here.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as well. A difference between the two versions is that without `normal`, the column is well moved to the match, whereas with it, it only moves to the start of the matched line. But both of them don't change the highlighting.